# KilledWorker exception using Dask on 1 machine and a large dataset?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

so my problem is that I have tried to read a large file (almost 12GB, on my 16gb RAM PC), but every time I try to do some operations on the Dask dataframe, something goes wrong and an exception such as KilledWorker exception happens...

I am not using any clusters, and I have tried to use pandas, but the RAM would go up to 100%, so I don't think I have a choice other than Dask at the moment.

Please check out a snippet of my code:

```
from dask.distributed import Client, progress
client = Client()
client

ddf = dd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\bigfile1.csv', encoding="latin-1", dtype="str")

mylist_a =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h','i']
daskfile1 = ddf.loc[:, ~ddf.columns.isin(mylist_a)].compute()
```

Here are the errors:

```
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker process 10292 was killed by signal 15
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://127.0.0.1:6585'], ('try_loc-ebb1f07a0b9e9ef0362fea6ff6407461', 76)
distributed.client - WARNING - Couldn't gather 200 keys, rescheduling {"('try_loc-ebb1f07a0b9e9ef0362fea6ff6407461', 76)": ('tcp://127.0.0.1:6585',), "('try_loc-ebb1f07a0b9e9ef0362fea6ff6407461', 161)": ('tcp://127.0.0.1:6628',), "('try_loc-ebb1f07a0b9e9ef0362fea6ff6407461', 51)": ('tcp://127.0.0.1:6568',), "('try_loc-ebb1f07a0b9e9ef0362fea6ff6407461', 156)": ('tcp://127.0.0.1:6568',), "('try_loc-ebb1f07a0b9e9ef0362fea6ff6407461', 58)": ('tcp://127.0.0.1:6585',), "('try_loc-ebb1f07a0b9e9ef0362fea6ff6407461', 176)": ('tcp://127.0.0.1:6628',),

distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://127.0.0.1:6715'], ('try_loc-ebb1f07a0b9e9ef0362fea6ff6407461', 66)
```

And here is the Exception:

```
KilledWorker                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-38194b0211e6> in <module>
      3 # df = ddf.compute()
      4 
----> 5 daskfile1 = ddf.loc[:, ~ddf.columns.isin(mylist_a)].compute()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
    154         dask.base.compute
    155         """
--> 156         (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    157         return result
    158 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    396     keys = [x.__dask_keys__() for x in collections]
    397     postcomputes = [x.__dask_postcompute__() for x in collections]
--> 398     results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    399     return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
    400 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py in get(self, dsk, keys, restrictions, loose_restrictions, resources, sync, asynchronous, direct, retries, priority, fifo_timeout, actors, **kwargs)
   2330             try:
   2331                 results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous,
-> 2332                                       direct=direct)
   2333             finally:
   2334                 for f in futures.values():

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py in gather(self, futures, errors, maxsize, direct, asynchronous)
   1654             return self.sync(self._gather, futures, errors=errors,
   1655                              direct=direct, local_worker=local_worker,
-> 1656                              asynchronous=asynchronous)
   1657 
   1658     @gen.coroutine

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py in sync(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    674             return future
    675         else:
--> 676             return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
    677 
    678     def __repr__(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\utils.py in sync(loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
    275             e.wait(10)
    276     if error[0]:
--> 277         six.reraise(*error[0])
    278     else:
    279         return result[0]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\utils.py in f()
    260             if timeout is not None:
    261                 future = gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=timeout), future)
--> 262             result[0] = yield future
    263         except Exception as exc:
    264             error[0] = sys.exc_info()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py in run(self)
    727 
    728                     try:
--> 729                         value = future.result()
    730                     except Exception:
    731                         exc_info = sys.exc_info()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py in run(self)
    734                     if exc_info is not None:
    735                         try:
--> 736                             yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
    737                         finally:
    738                             # Break up a reference to itself

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py in _gather(self, futures, errors, direct, local_worker)
   1495                             six.reraise(type(exception),
   1496                                         exception,
-> 1497                                         traceback)
   1498                     if errors == 'skip':
   1499                         bad_keys.add(key)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

KilledWorker: ("('from-delayed-pandas_read_text-read-block-try_loc-ebb1f07a0b9e9ef0362fea6ff6407461', 36)", 'tcp://127.0.0.1:6717')
```

I just want to do this relatively simple operation on a large data size
(please note that I only showed a snippet of the errors, since there are a lot)

Any type of help would be appreciated

Comment: if you look in the task manager, what is the maximum amount of memory consumed? Also, check out https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html#memory-management

Comment: It's almost 15.5GB, and then it drops (I guess this happens when a worker dies)
To be honest with you, I have came across this web page, but I have no idea on what should I change in the settings

Comment: does the issue also occur, if you load in fewer columns?

Comment: Try without parallelism, the memory load should be much lower: `...compute(scheduler='single-threaded')`

Comment: @ArcoBast No, it worked fine with a smaller dataset, although the RAM usage went up to 15GB

Comment: @malbert okay I'm gonna try it now and get back to you

Comment: @malbert it's running, and taking a lot of time (expected due to single thread), but the memory usage is still very high, it's reaching 15.5GB
Do you think that's normal?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pandas and dask dataframes. For some reason it seems to need to load your entire file into memory...

Comment: @malbert I believe that it is reading from the storage as well, because the disk usage is 100%

Comment: how many partitions does `ddf` have?

Comment: @ArcoBast I'm not sure what you meant by that, but

Cluster
Workers: 4
Cores: 8
Memory: 17.08 GB

If that's not what you're asking, please let me know how can I provide the number of partitions

Comment: try `ddf.npartitions` .. it is the number of pandas dataframes your dask dataframe consists of. For the general concept of a dask dataframe, have a look here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html#design

Comment: @ArcoBast it returned 200

Comment: how much memory does `daskfile1` take? another way to approach this could be not to call compute at that point. instead, you could extend the dask graph until it represents your final desired result and then call compute.

Comment: @ArcoBast the file size I'm working with is almost 12GB, while whenever I'm processing daskfile1, the memory consumption goes up to 15.8 at some time

Unfortunately, I couldn't extend the graph anymore, the result I want is just to use the .loc on the large ddf.

Comment: so the goal is to have a large pandas dataframe in memory?

Comment: @ArcoBast no not at all, it's the opposite actually, I'm gonna work with almost 40GB of data so I'm trying out with this 12GB

There's no way I could put all this data in memory so that's why I'm using Dask

I want to read the huge data from storage

Comment: can you further describe your workflow? what fraction of data ends up in daskfile1? dask will not reduce the memory footprint, if it is solely used to read in data.

Comment: @ArcoBast okay so I'm basically splitting my huge dataframe into only the columns that I want
My goal is very basic, it's just to read this huge data, and perform loc on it
And then export it as CSV

Comment: Then I would call `to_csv` instead of `compute`. You should end up with `npartitions` csv files containing the filtered dataset.

Comment: @ArcoBast I don't think 200 partitions would be a good idea :p

Also I wanna apply the remove duplicates method

And I wanna end up with 1 file

Comment: you can concatenate the files later, after processing ... as it is plain text, that should be easy to to.